# PHP EXCEL Number Format

Tags: sql, phpexcel

I'm using a PHPExcel Library to Export my database to excel...
I have a value **200010058502** to be exported but it will appear as **2.0001E+11** in the excel file

Any idea how to format this to make the value the same in my database

My PHPExcel code to fetch value from the database:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("J".$xlsRow,$row['acct_no']);
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is an Excel display issue, not a PHP issue.

To verify that the number is imported correctly, highlight the cell and check the status bar.  It should show the entire number, and not in scientific notation.  If it doesn't, ignore the rest of my answer.

Increase the width of your Excel cell to be more than 11 digits wide.  Excel will automatically convert numbers to scientific notation that are too large to physically fit in the display.  If it still is in scientific notation, change the formatting of the cell (cell->format->number) to show a number with zero decimal places.

Comment: I guess I found the answer, you just need to use setCellValueExplicit() with a type of string. Thanks for your comment though